# Group & Sort function MS Access 2010 returning only first row

Tags: report, ms-access-2010, grouping

I am having an issue with MS Access 2010 when creating a report from a query I have.

I cannot share anything of the code or any print due to copyright concerns, but I will try to describe the problem as simple as I can.

I have a query that returns some data for populating my report. Let's say, this is the data returned:

```
Group   CreationDate   Price
1       11/05/2010     $3.55 
1       01/07/2011     $0.9
2       01/01/2011     $1.00
2       09/19/2014     $9.05
2       07/30/2006     $6.99
3       03/22/2011     $4.56
3       05/21/2008     $5.23
```

I grouped it all by "Group" and I expected to have:

```
Group CreationDate   Price
1       
        11/05/2010     $3.55 
        01/07/2011     $0.9
2  
        01/01/2011     $1.00
        09/19/2014     $9.05
        07/30/2006     $6.99
3
        03/22/2011     $4.56
        05/21/2008     $5.23
```

What I have instead is:

```
Group   CreationDate   Price
1       
        11/05/2010     $3.55 
        11/05/2010     $3.55 
2  
        01/01/2011     $1.00
        01/01/2011     $1.00
        01/01/2011     $1.00
3
        03/22/2011     $4.56
        03/22/2011     $4.56
```

MS Access is repeating the first row for every group. Any idea on what may be causing this??

The query for my report is this:

```
SELECT AllInfo.*
FROM (SELECT i.ID, i.[Number], IIF( i.ProjectType = 'Type1', p.Code,     fp.Code) As Code, ic.[Comment], ic.[Date] AS CommentDate FROM tbProj AS p RIGHT JOIN ((tbItems AS i LEFT JOIN tbFprojects AS fp ON i.ProjectID = fp.Id) LEFT JOIN tbItemsComm AS ic ON ic.ItemID = i.ID) ON i.ProjectID = p.Id GROUP BY i.ID, i.[Number], i.DateOpened, ic.Comment, p.Code, fp.Code)  AS AllInfo;
```

The grouping I do in my report (visually using Access Group & Sort tool) is it:

```
Sort By Code
    Group On Number
          Sort By CommentDate
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you didn't write your query properly. But since you can't show us the query, we can't help you.

Comment: Why would you post a question with a whole bunch of datasets, but not show the query that potentially could have been debugged?

Comment: I am not very used to Microsoft Access so, here is a question: does the grouping function change my query in some way or does it perform the grouping after the query returns the result set? If the later option is the correct, then it will not help anyhow to show my query, since when I run it purely it fetches the correct results. Anyway, I am going to change the table names and post it here.

Comment: I edited it, Lynn and Marc, and posted the query now.